# Starting RoR server as a daemon makes File.read fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon

I have a RoR app that is working as expected when the server is started normally (`rails s`), but when I start the server as a daemon, I am getting an error when I run `File.read (<filename>)`:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - <filename>
```

This file clearly exists because it works when not started as a daemon.

How should I fix this so that I can start the development server as a daemon?

Comment: It sounds like a path or permissions problem to me, but without further information it'd be hard to diagnose. Can you post the full stack trace or the value of <filename> (or, at least an anonymized version?)

Comment: Sounds like you are starting in a separate work dir when running as a daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - In order to make the paths correct here, I have to do:

```
Rails.root.join(<filename>)
```

Then it works!